# Write to a Parse column after query - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How can I use a query to find the currentUser from a Parse Class and then write data into that user columns?

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"User")
    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    println(object.objectId)

                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must not save in to the user class.  Make a new table for that. Lamar has explained it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)
```

To:

```
query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser().objectId)
```

And also if you are querying from the parse user class it should be **_User** not **User**

To Only save data

```
 var ObjectToSave = PFObject(className: "_User")
 ObjectToSave["raw"] = "whateveryoulike"
 ObjectToSave["UserId"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId // this piece of code is when you create a new class 
    ObjectToSave.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
          println("data was saved")
        }
        else
        {
        println("error")
        }
    }
}
```

**I don't think it is a good idea to save other data into the _User class, you should leave this class for the login or sign up. You should create a new class then save all new data with the userid...**

Comment: I have a column with the name "rua", how can i write something there?

Comment: so you want to save new information to this class not retrieve it right ?

Comment: Yes.  The columns right now are empty and i want to save data.

Comment: I dont undertstand your code. Why `ObjectToSave["objectId"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId`? I already have the ObjectId saved, I just need a query for the currentUser and then save data to other columns.

Comment: the reason that i wrote this code because I would be better to create a new class ... so with the objectId you could identify which user who post that material

Comment: Ok i will create a new class, but if i create a new class the code will not work because i will need a relational query right?

Comment: no relation query ...So when you create a new class let say you called **Data** right and then you had two column **userID** and **raw** so to save data into that new class just the code i gave you and replace the className to **Data** that is it my friend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87283/discussion-between-renato-pimpao-and-lamar).

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to query for the current user.
Use this

```
var user = PFUser.currentUser()
user["one"] = "whateveryoulike"
user["two"] = "whateveryoulike"

 user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success:Bool, error:NSError?) ->  Void in
    if error == nil{
      println("data was saved")
    }
    else
    {
    println("error")
    }
}
```

}